# Generalized Jordan theorem and winding number

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, real-analysis

By the generalized Jordan theorem any continuous injective map 
$S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow R^n$ splits $R^n$ into two regions, one being bounded (interior) and the other one unbounded (exterior). It must exist a stronger statement that the winding number for the points of the interior with respect to this sphere is always $\pm 1$. Anybody can tell me a reference how this theorem is called and who must be given credit for?

In fact a friend of mine asked me a different question. Is it true that any continuous injective map $R^n\hookrightarrow R^n$ is always open? I expect the answer is yes. It can be easily reduced to the previous one, but perhaps there is a simpler proof?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your first question the credit goes to Brouwer. It's sometimes called the *Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem*. In this context you do not need a sphere, your $n-1$-manifold can be any compact connected boundaryless submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.   I believe both appear in the Guillemin and Pollack textbook, and Bredon's Topology and Geometry textbook.

Your last question has the *yes* answer expected. The proof is very much similar.  I'm not sure if I would call either proof easier than the other.  This one tends to be called the *open mapping theorem* and at this level of generality you would need Bredon's book, but most intro algebraic topology texts that cover singular homology cover this.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I will check the references, but I am not convinced by your answer as the theorem in question only states that the complement consists of two regions - unbounded and bounded. It does not imply that the winding number is one for the points of the interior region.

Comment: The proof in the Guillemin and Pollack textbook provides this. Technically they are using mod-2 degrees in their proof but that is only because integer-valued degrees are not defined at that point. But if you re-do their proof using integer-valued degrees it gives you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

A statement that is both stronger and simpler to state is: *For compact subsets of   $\mathbb{R}^n$, the number of connected components of the complement is a topologic invariant.* This is an immediate consequence of the [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) (See e.g. Spanier's *Algebraic Topology* Ch. 6, Theorem 16). There is also an elementary proof, I believe due to Leray, by means of the Browder degree; you can find a very clear exposition of it in Louis Nirenberg's *Topics in Nonlinear Functional Analysis*.

Comment: Pietro, thank you for your answer. I don't think that the Alexander duality helps here to determine the winding number.

Comment: I am sorry, actually you are right. The geometrical interpretation of the Alexander duality is through the linking number, and the winding number in our case is its particular occurrence.